# What is the meaning of y

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

What does *y* mean in "Sa mère craignait qu'il n'y soit mécontent" which is translated as "his mother was afraid that he might be unhappy"? I know "il y a" means "there is" but it seems not applicable here.

Comment: Always try "there" first, as a learner. Same with "in there", "to there". If that makes no sense, try "about ___", whatever makes sense in context. That covers almost all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation missed the ***y***.

The meaning is:

> His mother was afraid that he might be unhappy **there**.

I think I would have chose "worried" instead of "afraid".

Comment: So *y* could mean *there* sometimes, right?

Comment: Definitely, also *it*, *them* and probably others.

Comment: How do you know the *y* means *there* and not *about that*?

Comment: Because that would have read *qu'il n'**en** soit mécontent*.

Answer (score 0):

J’abonde sur la réponse de jjliagre.
Le « y » en français indique un endroit (réel ou fictif))

Exemples :

J’y mettrais plus de sel (après avoir goûter un plat)

J’y suis déjà allé (en parlant du Mont-Saint-Michel)

Je n’y ai jamais mis les pieds (en parlant de l’Enfer)

Vas-y!

D’une façon générale, le « y » fait référence à quelque chose qui se se trouve dans la phrase d’avant.
Si je reprends mes exemples:

Comment trouves-tu ma soupe?

Que penses-tu du Mont-Saint-Michel?

Pourrais-tu survivre en Enfer?

Et pour le dernier « vas-y! » c’est une expression courante pour « fonce! Pas d’hésitation ! »

Comment: _Le « y » en français indique un endroit (réel ou fictif))_ : [Pas uniquement](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y/1), il peut aussi représenter un complément ou une proposition entière. Dans l'exemple en question il peut représenter un lieu.